# Adding variable in PowerPoint using OpenXML

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml, openxml-sdk, office-addins

As we can add a Document Variable with the help of DocumentVariables class in MS word using OpenXML,what is the similar way to add a variable in PowerPoint using OpenXML.
I want to add a property (variable) in  PowerPoint where a user can not remove this easily.

Comment: Powerpoint doesn't have document variables, but you can use tags (on presentation, slide or individual shapes).  I don't know how the tags are expressed in OXML, but you could add one with VBA then look at the results.  ActivePresentation.Tags.Add "MyTagName", "MyTagValue"

Comment: Thanks Steve,I will try tags